# Nested fraction with factorial

Tags: factorial, fractions

In a statistics book I'm studying, I'm given the following:

$\frac{\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{\frac{8!}{3!5!}}{\frac{10!}{3!7!}}=\frac{8\times7\times6}{10\times9\times8}=\frac{42}{90}=0.47$

I don't understand how $\frac{\frac{8!}{3!5!}}{\frac{10!}{3!7!}}$ became $\frac{8\times7\times6}{10\times9\times8}$.

What's the trick used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{8!}{5!}=\frac{8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5!}{5!}=8 \times 7 \times 6$$

$$\frac{10!}{7!}=\frac{10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7!}{7!}= 10 \times 9 \times 8$$

$3!$ terms get canceled out.

Comment: Why are you adding $5!$ and $7!$ to the beginning of the numerators?

Comment: $8!=8 \times 7 \times 6 \times (5!)$ right?

Comment: Oh, right, plain and simple...

Comment: Why are the $3!$ terms canceled out?

Comment: hmmm $\frac{\frac1{3!}}{\frac1{3!}}=1$ right?